# Can the local development server be used to only simulate Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-kubernetes-engine

If I'm developing an application that will run on the google container engine, but still wish for it to use cloud datastore, do I have any options to simulate cloud datastore for local development?

Please note for the sake of correctly understanding my question: My application will not be Python, PHP or Java.  It will not be running via App Engine, but via Container Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using cloud datastore's [local development server](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver)? It sounds like exactly what you are looking for.